# The problem of baud rate when using sicktoolbox_wrapper!

Tags: ros, sicklms, sicktoolbox-wrapper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am having a problem of baud rate with sick lms200 laser when using sicktoolbox_wrapper. I am using ubuntu 10.04 and ROS electric. I followed the tutorial on
http://www.ros.org/wiki/sicktoolbox_wrapper/Tutorials/UsingTheSicklms

When I set the baud rate to be 38400: rosparam set sicklms/baud 38400.The laser works well,but there is a waring:

```
                A scan was probably missed.
```

However,when I set the baud rate to be 500000,the laser can't work ,of course ,the baud of laser is 500k.The error is as follow:

```
     Attempting to set requested baud rate...
A Timeout Occurred!  2 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred!  1 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred - SickLIDAR::_sendMessageAndGetReply: Attempted max number of tries w/o success!
    Failed to set requested baud rate...
    Attempting to detect LMS baud rate...
        Checking 19200bps...
A Timeout Occurred!  2 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred!  1 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred - SickLIDAR::_sendMessageAndGetReply: Attempted max number of tries w/o success!
        Checking 38400bps...
A Timeout Occurred!  2 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred!  1 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred - SickLIDAR::_sendMessageAndGetReply: Attempted max number of tries w/o success!
        Checking 500Kbps...
A Timeout Occurred!  2 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred!  1 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred - SickLIDAR::_sendMessageAndGetReply: Attempted max number of tries w/o success!
ERROR: I/O exception - SickLMS::Initialize: failed to detect baud rate!
[ERROR] [1346919668.935157216]: Initialize failed! are you using the correct device path?
```

Is someone using the sicklms200 with the baud rate of 500k well? Maybe you can give me some advices!
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46430/the-problem-of-baud-rate--when-using-sicktoolbox_wrapper!/) by [dllg_211](https://answers.ros.org/users/3429/dllg_211/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jimbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4830/jimbo/) on 2013-05-08**:
Attempting to sync driver...
Driver synchronized!
*** Init. complete: Sick LMS is online and ready!
Sick Type: Sick LMS 291-S14
Scan Angle: 90 (deg)
Scan Resolution: 0.5 (deg)
Measuring Mode: 8m/80m; 3 reflector bits
Measuring Units: Centimeters (cm)

[ INFO] [1368060282.802058549]: Variant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Try to update the baud rate to 19200 and after change to 38400 again. It solved to me.

---

Originally posted by [Cássio](https://answers.ros.org/users/5385/c%C3%A1ssio/) with karma: 16 on 2013-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0